# Lenovo y540 has various problems

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop, water-damage

This is so bizarre.

I have Lenovo y540. I used to put it on my lap while using. I UVed it so the temps were under control.

For last few days, my touchpad went unresponsive after gaming. Since it resumed working after a reboot, I didn't bat an eye.

Soon after my webcam went awol. Like it works for a few seconds after starting. But soon after it goes black or horribly distorted.

Same with my speakers. After a while, there is distortion equivalent to earr@pe.

So I got it checked at lenovo. Turns out, oil from my lap went through the heatsink, to my motherboard. WTF?

He cleaned the surface of the board. Then it worked just fine. But after booting at home, the problem is still persistent and increasing.

Should I continue using with a hope that so called oil will eventually evaporate, or get it wiped again, to remove oil, if its even possible?

ps. I can't afford board replacement.

Comment: What kind of oil are we talking about here? Oily skin?

Comment: Define "oil", AFAIK most kinds of oil are good insulators, they are not conductive, so you shouldn't have any problem if oil comes in contact with your computer's electronic parts.